# Angularjs Unified view of two lists

Tags: java, angularjs, jpa

I'm working in an app with Angularjs and java spring server application.

I got a table which takes data from 2 lists containing objects different but correlated:

Object in list 1: `{id, category_id, unit_cost, qty}`, coming from db_table1.

Object in list 2: `{id, category_id, unit_cost, qty}`, coming from db_table2.

The objects are correlated by category_id and differ in id and qty. 
There may be cases when for a given category_id only one of the two objects exists.

I want to show a component with rows as follow

```
object_1.id, category_id, unit_cost, obj1.qty, obj1.qty*cost obj2.qty, obj2.qty*cost
```

(one row per category_id).

Rows must include all cases, so:

- when for a category there are both obj1 and obj2
- when for a category there are only obj1 or obj2

Which is the most efficient method of build this list ?

- on client side in component controller
- on server side, in spring service

Comment: I think the best way to join these tables while querying at server side.

Comment: In general - on server side. Java >> javascript: more readable, platform independent, easier to test, etc. etc. So in usual situation always prefer server solutions.